# javac and java commands through Windows batch files

Tags: java, batch-file, javac

I normally compile things through the command line using:

```
javac -classpath . Test.java
```

Similarly, I run them through:

```
java -classpath . Test
```

I'm now attempting to save myself the trouble of typing these out every time through batch files. I have attempted to do so through another question from here:

[Creating a batch file, for simple javac and java command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147613/creating-a-batch-file-for-simple-javac-and-java-command-execution/6147683#6147683)

I've also tried my own way:

```
cmd.exe
@echo off
javac -classpath . Test.java
```

Still no luck, however. I have checked that my PATH environment variable is correctly pointing to the latest version of jdk and as I've said, I can compile just fine directly through command line. Upon running the batch file, I just get the command prompt with no error; as if there was nothing under cmd.exe. Could anyone lend a helping hand and slap some sense into me?

Comment: I've done that, what happens is a command prompt shows up but instantly closes down again. It doesn't compile anything either.

As for the dot in the last line, do you mean the . after -classpath? javac won't let me compile even through the command line without it.

Comment: Thanks! Consider putting that down as an answer so I can choose it. I had cmd.exe to simply keep an open command prompt but it seems like it was the culprit. I don't know what the dot is for but javac won't let me compile without it so I just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `cmd.exe`, that will start a new command prompt. You don't want that.

When you write `@echo off`, that means **nothing will be printed on the screen** after that point. That's what it means. That's what it does. That is why it looks like nothing is happening.

Something would be printed to the screen if you had a compilation error, but probably you don't.

If you want the command prompt window to stay around instead of disappearing, I believe there is an option in Windows to configure that, at least there was when I last used Windows, back in the mists of time.

Comment: Put `pause` at the end of the file.

Comment: I fully intended to have @echo off to not print the javac -classpath command. What was weird was that I could compile Test.java perfectly fine from command line manually but it simply wasn't having any effect from the batch file at all. I still don't fully understand why that is, but I suppose I don't really have to.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. I think it does what you were looking to do.

This is the code I suggest for the .bat file:

```
cd C:\Users\John\JavaApps\folderThatContains.java //points terminal to folder

javac Main.java  //This compiles .java in said folder

cmd /K "java Main" //cmd /K prevents terminal from quitting after "java Main"
```

Comment: Note: "java main" must be in quotes after 'cmd /K'